# WooCommerce one time checkout pop up

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

please help me out fixing this..

I want a BUY NOW button next to ADD TO CART, and when the buy now button is clicked, a pop up showing the product price, and a form to be completed by the user will be shown.

After completing it, those info should be visible to the site admin, the product must not be added to the cart ( if he had 2 products in the cart before clicking the BUY NOW button, after completion, those two must be the only products to remain there too)

NB: I have tried these plugins already;

1. Yith one time checkout: this works only if a client is logged in, and my target here are non logged in users. Otherwise this was the perfect one.
2. Stripe one click checkout plugin by Woocommerce: Stripe works only in 26 countries, mine isn't one of them.
3. Paypal one click checkout plugin by store apps: this one is a premium one, and it seems to be expensive.

Any plugin or code snippets that can make it work is accepted

Does any of you  have a better solution guys, please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Hi with both PayPal and Stripe you can export a button code that you can then insert into your product template, if it's not for all products you'll then need to work out a conditional rule/s to handle the exceptions. https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button#create-and-mount-element

Comment: Stripe doesn't work in my country, the Paypal plugin you gave me is so expensive

Comment: True about Stripe sorry, but you can create a PayPal button in a similar way - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buy_now_step_1/

Comment: With this stripe plugin?

Comment: Maybe this? https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-simple-buy-now/ I'll get out of the way now, I'm sure others have more ideas for this.

Comment: That wasn't working. It adds the product to the cart and checkout after

Comment: Thanks for trying to help though